# Convert hash to array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-hash

I have hash, all its values are arrays, like this:

```
list = { letter:  ['a', 'b', 'c'],
         number:  ['one', 'two', 'three'],
         fruit:   ['apple', 'pear', 'kiwi'],
         car:     ['vw', 'mb', 'bmw'],
         state:   ['la', 'ny', 'fl'],
         color:   ['red', 'white', 'black'],
         tree:    ['oak', 'pine', 'maple'],
         animal:  ['cat', 'dog', 'rat'],
         clothes: ['tie', 'sock', 'glove'] }
```

In fact this hash could have more keys and values could be larger, but always sizes of every value are the same (in this case - three).

I want to convert this hash to array of hashes.

Each hash will have all keys of origin hash and respective value.

So finally I want to have:

```
list = [
  { letter: 'a', number: 'one', fruit: 'apple', car: 'vw', state: 'la',
    color: 'red', tree: 'oak', animal: 'cat', clothes: 'tie' },

  { letter: 'b', number: 'two', fruit: 'pear', car: 'mb', state: 'ny',
    color: 'white', tree: 'pine', animal: 'dog', clothes: 'sock' },

  { letter: 'c', number: 'three', fruit: 'kiwi', car: 'bmw', state: 'fl',
    color: 'black', tree: 'elm', animal: 'rat', clothes: 'glove' }
]
```

What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leveraging [Array#transpose](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Array.html#method-i-transpose) and [Array#to_h](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Array.html#method-i-to_h)

```
keys = list.keys
list.values.transpose.map { |v| keys.zip(v).to_h }
```

Comment: Similarly `keys = list.keys; list.values.transpose.map { |v| [keys, v].transpose.to_h }`

Comment: Not similarly, more like, why wouldn't I just map the values... :p I'll update, thanks

Answer (score 9):

```
[list.keys].product(list.values.transpose).map { |a| a.transpose.to_h }
   #=> [{:letter=>"a", :number=>"one", :fruit=>"apple", :car=>"vw", 
   #     :state=>"la", :color=>"red", :tree=>"oak", :animal=>"cat",
   #     :clothes=>"tie"},
   #    {:letter=>"b", :number=>"two", :fruit=>"pear", :car=>"mb",
   #     :state=>"ny", :color=>"white", :tree=>"pine", :animal=>"dog",
   #     :clothes=>"sock"},
   #    {:letter=>"c", :number=>"three", :fruit=>"kiwi", :car=>"bmw",
   #     :state=>"fl", :color=>"black", :tree=>"maple", :animal=>"rat", 
   #     :clothes=>"glove"}]
```

Suppose `list` were defined as follows.

```
list = {
  letter:  ['a',     'b'   ],
  number:  ['one',   'two' ],
  fruit:   ['apple', 'pear'],
  car:     ['vw',    'mb'  ]
}
```

The steps would be as follows.

```
b = [list.keys]
  #=> [[:letter, :number, :fruit, :car]]
c = list.values
  #=> [["a", "b"], ["one", "two"], ["apple", "pear"], ["vw", "mb"]]
d = c.transpose
  #=> [["a", "one", "apple", "vw"],
  #    ["b", "two", "pear",  "mb"]]
e = b.product(d)
  #=> [[[:letter, :number, :fruit, :car], ["a", "one", "apple", "vw"]],
  #    [[:letter, :number, :fruit, :car], ["b", "two", "pear",  "mb"]]]
e.map { |a| a.transpose.to_h }
  #=> [{:letter=>"a", :number=>"one", :fruit=>"apple", :car=>"vw"},
  #    {:letter=>"b", :number=>"two", :fruit=>"pear",  :car=>"mb"}]
```

Let's look at the last step more closely. `map` passes the first element of `e` to the block and sets the block variable `a` to its value:

```
a = e.first
  #=> [[:letter, :number,  :fruit,  :car],
  #    ["a",     "one",    "apple", "vw"]]
```

The block calculation is as follows.

```
f = a.transpose
  #=> [[:letter, "a"], [:number, "one"], [:fruit, "apple"], [:car,   "vw"]]
f.to_h
  #=> {:letter=>"a", :number=>"one", :fruit=>"apple", :car=>"vw"}
```

The remaining calculations for `e.map { |a| a.transpose.to_h }` are similar.

Comment: This is similar to @Marcin's answer. The main difference is that I used [Array#product](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-product) and used [Array#transpose](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-transpose) rather than [Enumerable#zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip), the latter being yin and yang.

Comment: @mechnicov, thanks for the compliment and also for mentioning the problem with the mixed-up lists. I fixed that.

Answer (score 3):

All in one:

```
list.map{|k,v| [k].product(v)}.transpose.map(&:to_h)
```

The idea is to use each key product its values, map out, transpose, then convert to hash by `to_h`.

Comment: 1. `map` is more idiomatic than `collect` 2. `each_pair` is superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

Try following code,

```
arr = []
3.times { |x| arr[x] = {}; list.each { |k,v| arr[x][k] = v[x] } }
arr.inspect
```

Output will be

```
=> [{:letter=>"a", :number=>"one", :fruit=>"apple", :car=>"vw", :state=>"la", :color=>"red", :tree=>"oak", :animal=>"cat", :clothes=>"tie"}, {:letter=>"b", :number=>"two", :fruit=>"pear", :car=>"mb", :state=>"ny", :color=>"white", :tree=>"pine", :animal=>"dog", :clothes=>"sock"}, {:letter=>"c", :number=>"three", :fruit=>"kiwi", :car=>"bmw", :state=>"fl", :color=>"black", :tree=>"maple", :animal=>"rat", :clothes=>"glove"}]
```

Comment: Where does the `3` come from?

Comment: For his case, 3 is taken by inspecting `list`. He can take it dynamically from `list` by some required logic. If needed, I will provide it also :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to play with [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
list.values.transpose.each_with_object([]) { |v, a| a << v.each_with_index.with_object({}) { |(vv, i), h| h[list.keys[i]] = vv } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Array::new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-c-new) as new array "builder" and [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) as every item "builder"

```rb
Array.new(list.first.last.size) do |index|
  list.each_with_object({}) { |(key, values), new_item| new_item[key] = values[index] }
end
```